# How to start a service on Boot in those device where BOOT_COMPLETE Intent is not working like one plus 6

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

How to start a service on Boot in those device where BOOT_COMPLETE Intent is not working like one plus 6.
It seem my device is not listening to BOOT_COMPLETE i have given BOOT_RECIEVED permission also in manifest. I have run the app but nothing seems working on other hand all standards app are working now. WHat should i do in this scenario

below is error log :

```
018-11-06 05:25:34.994 885-3000/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=oneplus.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE flg=0x10 } to test.myapplication/.MyReceiver
2018-11-06 05:25:38.241 885-3000/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to test.myapplication/.MyReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

Comment: In this case Android application developer can't do a thing.

Comment: any other intent i can register to ??

Comment: Look up here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#constants_1

Comment: i have pasted the error log. please check